# Disable "... not supported by Excel for Mac 2011" dialog box

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2011

When I use the following line to open an xls file, sometimes there is a dialog box popping up.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & fFile, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever, Password:="", ReadOnly:=True
```

[image]

My question is, whether it is possible to always make `Open as Read-Only` as default, disable the dialog box or do not let it interrupt the execution of my macro.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`? Place it just before the `.Open` and right after place `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` not sure it'll be enough though...

Comment: I have tried, it did not help...

Comment: I've looked around a bit, but it seems that Excel for Mac is the problem here... If you can run that on a PC, you should have any problems (not with ActiveX nor with DisplayAlerts). Hope for you someone find some workaround...

Comment: Does "Excel for Mac" have a macro recorder?

Comment: Sure, "Excel for Mac" has a macro recorder...